# Is it possible to maximize the dimension of a specific image according to the size of a browser window using greasemonkey/tampermonkey?

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, maximize

For instance if I have a gallery of images that I can browse through, sometimes having multiple galleries open, I have to be careful in resizing one window because it will resize differently for another one of the same page.

The best example I can think of is when you open an image by itself in a new tab and it's auto resized proportionally in the middle of the page no matter big or small the window is. No scrolling required

If it helps here's an example of the code code where the image is shown

```html
<div id="i3">
     <a onclick="return load_image(2, 'f46ef2b433')" href="https://testsite.com/b/f46ef2b433/1341428-2">
       <img id="img" src="http://testsite.com/fold01/5dde3b620790893d3ffab2da2437077dd41b31cf-230842-1280-1820-jpg/keystamp=1550591100-88d6d61f5f;fileindex=66272627;xres=2400/_000.jpg" 
         style="height: 1820px; width: 1280px; max-width: 1280px; max-height: 1820px;" onerror="this.onerror=null; nl('27617-430719')"></a></div>
```

the xpath is: //*[@id="img"]

I've seen plugins do this with videos but I'm looking to just do it with an image. Looking at other "similar" examples is confusing me more than helping at this point

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var x;
    x = document.getElementById("img");
    x.style.maxHeight = "100vh";
    x.style.maxWidth = "100vw";
    x.style.width = "";
    x.style.height = "";
    x.style.position = "fixed";
    x.style.top = "0";
    x.style.left = "15%";
})();
```

Here is my current updated script. i've been unable to change the max-height and max-with values but everything else has worked out for the most part. Without that, I'm not able to finish the task unless there's another method

`x.setAttribute("style", "max-Height: 100vh");`

this works but wiped away all of the other attributes...

both seem to work only in the console and not in the script as far as modifying the max height and max width values. there's no problem with changing other values

Comment: Did you try to set max-width: 100% and max-height: 100%, without height and width, while ensuring parents containers can expend to window size ?

Comment: i'm not sure about that second part and how to make sure of that

Comment: ok i believe this to be the parent  
```<div id="i1" class="sni" style="width: 620px;max-width: 620px;">```
<br>

Comment: @spidyx
after disabling those values i'm able to change the width to 100% and actually have it show,. i can't figure out how to do the same thing for the height. the goal is to at least have them proportionately  maximized on the screen because some images happen to be longer than average. my window dimensions are 952x963 without the taskbar. i can't figure out how to get it to work the way i need it to it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you described, you can use `vh` and `vw` units. Those units are relative to the size of the viewport.
Try the following exemple in a empty page. The `display: body` on the image avoid to have a vertical scrollbar

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img {
    display: block;
    max-height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
  <img src="http://www.dummyimage.com/1000x4000/000/fff&text=1000x4000">
</a>
```

Comment: i'm 99% there now thanks to that. i'll just figure out how to center the image and that'll be it. I can at least translate it to tampermonkey on my own. i also added position: absolute

Comment: so far i've been able to inject everything into the code except for the max-height and max-width properties. using javascript, the variable names are supposed modified using "maxHeight" and "maxWidth" but I'm having no luck changing the values

Comment: i've updated the post to show the script if that helps

Comment: The script you have added works for me.
Try to use the developper tools in your browser to see what styles are applied to your image.

Comment: this appears to be an issue with tampermonkey and chrome and works as expected with firefox. the only issue now is getting the image to properly center as the dimensions change. i've had to change the value of "left" to compensate and I'm currently searching to see if there's a workaround to solve this

Comment: You can easily align items with Flexbox. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

If you are facing difficulties, I suggest you to open a new question, especially if it concern tampermonkey or greasemonkey

Comment: thanks. i will research more and come back with a different question